# Not able to connect to snowflake from powerbi using odbc driver

Tags: odbc, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting this error.
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://jaa09657:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=5bcbbadc-39d9-4271-9bf3-52393e2539af&request_guid=e145e6e8-502b-40c3-b7f2-4164dfbe6fea&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=5 msg='Couldn't resolve proxy name' osCode=2 osMsg='No such file or directory'.

Comment: Could you include your connection string that you are trying to connect with.  Often these issues are related to something wrong in there.

Comment: Make sure you are using the full account name including snowflakecomputing.com (and region if applicable). Additionally, I see "Couldn't resolve proxy name".  Is the proxy setup and configured? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#connecting-through-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with your server property, you just have your account name, but you really need the Fully Qualified Domain there.  IE:

server=jaa09657..snowflakecomputing.com

Base that on the URL you connect with.

If that does not work, could you provide your entire ODBC config?